# How do I call a class's function that has a receiver?

Tags: kotlin

How do I call a public extension function on a class that has a receiver?

```
interface CoroutineActivity {

    // how can I call this function in example below?
    fun CoroutineScope.onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
}

class CoroutineActivityDelegate(private val coroutineActivity: CoroutineActivity) {

    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val onCreateScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job())

        // how do I call an extension function with a receiver? This doesn't compile
        coroutineActivity.onCreate(onCreateScope, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Is it possible? I'd prefer `CoroutineScope` to be the receiver, rather than the first parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The function you described [is said to have two receivers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members), a *dispatch* receiver of type `CoroutineActivity` and an *extension* receiver of type `CoroutineScope`.

While there's no syntax to call this function by directly providing the two receivers, it can be called in a scope of its dispatch receiver type (i.e. in a scope where `this: CoroutineActivity`). These scopes are:

- scopes of members of `CoroutineActivity` and its subtypes;
- scopes of extensions with the *extension* receiver of type `CoroutineActivity` (or its subtypes);
- scopes of [function literals (lambdas) with a receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) of type `CoroutineActivity` (or its subtypes).

In a suitable scope, you can simply call the function on an instance of `CoroutineContext`.

The simplest way to do that is to use the standard library scoping functions `run { ... }` or `apply { ... }`, passing a lambda with receiver as follows:

```
coroutineActivity.run { 
    val onCreateScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job())
    onCreateScope.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```